# Bootstrap ".panel-heading" opacity?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, i'm trying to set the Bootstrap Panel-Heading to be transparent.
Because of the z-index i cannot figure out how to do it.

The panel-heading is on-top of panel-default.

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"></div>
  <div class="panel-body"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-default{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.panel-default .panel-heading{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
.panel-default .panel-body{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}
```

I've tried to make the whole panel (panel-default) transparent,
and then gave the body a white color. Problem here is that the panel-body isn't cover the whole space below the heading. I just got a white area where i have some content/text.

If i make the panel-default solid white, i cannot "get thru" it with transparent panel-heading. Because the heading is on-top of the panel-default.

**UPDATE**
So my problem is that i'd like the heading to be transparent, but the body to be solid. AND the body to cover whole space below panel-heading.

**EDIT**
I tried to set height for panel-body to 100% but it's still not covering the whole space below panel-heading.

[image]

**UPPDATE**
The problem on the panel-body aint cover whole space was because i had set the panel-default height. I should had set the panel-body height instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below CSS , may be it can be help to you.

**CSS**

```
.panel-default{
    background: transparent;
}
.panel-default .panel-heading{
    background: transparent;
}
.panel-default .panel-body{
   background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It does exactly what you asked: http://www.bootply.com/eNKQFNkEgB Except that `panel-heading ` should be semi-opaque rather than transparent

Comment: @Turnip as you can se in my edit photo. The panel-body isn't cover the whole bottom space, but maby that's not clear in my question...

Comment: ok, i'm sorry. My real problem was with height on panel-default. I will set this answer to correct.